# Как передать данные из select'a в базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Сделал массив из столбца базы данных, и сделал из него выпадающий список, теперь не могу понять, как передать выбранное значение из списка в другую таблицу базы данных, подскажите, в чем моя ошибка? Пробовал методом POST, но он не находит этот список.

```
$driver = array();
$result = mysqli_query($db_server, "SELECT `info` FROM `drivers`");
    while($myrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $driver[] = $myrow['info'];
}

echo '<select>';
foreach($driver as $item){
    echo '<option>'.$item.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: взять POST по name селекта. $_POST['select_name']. Котерова читайте.

Comment: Спасибо за совет по необходимой литературе, проблема решилась чередой случайных манипуляций, до этого же POST упорно отказывался брать данные.

Comment: можно же полностью смотреть что в пост находится print_r($_POST), но даже лучше $_REQUEST

Comment: @ПавелКаханов добавьте решение в текст вопроса, что бы люди столкнувшиеся с такой же проблемой могли его увидеть